# Is there a tool for linux like Shotwell or F-Spot, but for video?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, ubuntu-10.04

Shotwell helps me keep my photos organized. It would be nice if there was something similar for my videos. I prefer something Gtk-based, but I'm open to ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Pitivi](http://www.pitivi.org/) (should be installed by default, otherwise [install it](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/pitivi)) or [Openshot](http://www.openshotvideo.com/) ([install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/openshot)).